# Why the cookie will save the json again if I didn't freshen the webpage?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

When I click the button for the fist time,the form saved in cookie as follows:

```
1=[{"name":"1","num":"1","classAge":"1","score":"1"}];
```

and then I set the value of input as a "" to clear.
but if I fill in the form without F5 to freshen the webpage,the data that I saved before will saved again:

```
2=[{"name":"1","num":"1","classAge":"1","score":"1"},{"name":"2","num":"2","classAge":"2","score":"2"}];
```

And I don't know why.The code listed as follow.

```
oSubmit.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        oEvent = e||event;
        oEvent.preventDefault(); 
        iNum = oInput[1].value;
        var stu = new Object;                           
        stu = student(oInput[0].value,oInput[1].value,oInput[2].value,oInput[3].value);
        console.log(typeof stu);
        array1.push(stu);                       
        sJson = JSON.stringify(array1);             
        alert("OK！");
        for (var i=0;i<oInput.length;i++) {         
            oInput[i].value="";
        }
        setCookie(iNum,sJson,7);
        console.log(document.cookie);
    })
```

Comment: What does this student function do? Please make sure to include all your code.

Comment: The code shown never resets the `array1` variable, so yes, every time you call the function you will be adding to whatever was already in that array and then saving the whole thing in the cookie. You could add `var array1 = []` in the function, but if you only ever want to save the current value you don't need an array at all, just save `JSON.stringify(stu)`. As an aside, you don't need `oEvent = e||event;` if you're using `.addEventListener()`, and `stu = new Object;` is redundant because you immediately overwrite that value on the next line.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes,it is array1 that created trouble.Thanks~

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have formed an answer based on the comments by nnnnnn and the assumption that the `console.log` and `alert` is for debugging.
(If it's not, I can't possible imagine what it's for)

```
oSubmit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var studentResult = student(oInput[0].value, oInput[1].value, oInput[2].value, oInput[3].value);
    setCookie(oInput[1].value, JSON.stringify([studentResult]), 7);

    for (var i = 0; i < oInput.length; i++) {
        oInput[i].value = "";
    }
})
```

I also want to take the oppurtunity to give you some advice on allowing other programmers to understand your code better.

- It is not possible to determine or even half-accurately guess what the function `student` does. "student" is a noun, and if you put a verb in front of it, it becomes much clearer(`getStudent`, or such)
- It is not possible to determine what `oInput` is. What is the "o" for?
- You are using variables that are (probably/hopefully) declared outside of the presented scope, and without that information, any advice on how to solve your problem is guesswork.

I hope you will consider these suggestions.